# OpenGL ES 2 - color and texture in vertex

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm making a program with OpenGL ES 2.0.  I need to render a texture on top of another, like a clock hand.  The textures are both 1024 x 1024 and are transparent.  The transparency is always rendering black, and this is preventing me from overlaying the clock hand texture over the clock.

`simple_fragment_shader.glsl`

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() 
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

---

`simple_vertex_shader.glsl`

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;  
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()                    
{                            
    v_Color = a_Color;

    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;          
}
```

---

`texture_fragment_shader.glsl`

```
precision mediump float; 

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;                                        
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;                                          

void main()                         
{                               
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);    
}
```

---

`texture_vertex_shader.glsl`

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;  
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()                    
{                            
    v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;          
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;    
}
```

I'm kind of new at OpenGL, and I have used textures, but I don't know how to get the transparency.

Also, if this helps, I am sort of following the methods in *`OpenGL ES 2 for Android`* by Kevin Brothaler from *`The Pragmatic Programmers`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha value might be ignored without following settings.

glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

I hope this help you:)

Comment: Works great!  But there is a thin black outline around the textures, is this because of the resizing? And can I get rid of it? -Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great:) Please check the parameters of your sampler. Does this fix it? glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Comment: Actually, I changed the first parameter of `glBlendFunc()` to `GL_ONE`, and that solved it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that GL_ONE is additive blending (SCREEN_COLOR+TEXTURE_COLOR) which may perfectly hide black pixels on your texture (SCREEN_COLOR+0) but at the same time it may create unwanted overlit effect (when SCREEN_COLOR+TEXTURE_COLOR>1). So I recommend to fix alpha on your texture and use conventional alpha blending unless you want to have excatly an additive blending.